# How to pick a fallback site in Crafter Studio?

Tags: crafter-cms

I have an external REST client calling a service in a particular site in Crafter Studio. When the 'crafterSite' cookie is not set, Studio will fail the call and log this in catalina.out:

```
[WARN] 2018-03-15 19:50:50,015 [http-bio-7070-exec-4687] [] [context.SiteContextResolverImpl] | Unable to resolve a site name for the request. Using fallback site
```

Is there a way to set the fallback site to a specific site instead of the out-of-the-box default site?

Answer (score 0):

Add "crafterSite={site}" to the URL. See this document for more detail: http://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/system-administrators/engine/configure-engine-multi-tenancy.html?highlight=craftersite

Comment: I am looking for a way to point the default site away from the kid in a cape, so Studio will render the site I wanted when the 'crafterSite' parameter or cookie is *not* set.